# Redux + React Native + Expo - In development environment, component not rendered after updating state, but it works in production

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, state, expo

I encounter a problem with, I think, Expo environment

When my Redux State is updated, my components are not rendered, whereas in Production mode, everything works fine

I do not print my code because it's surely not related to code, but rather than Expo environnement. Some others developers encountered that problem, but I still not found a working solution ..
It's just annoying to code in Prod' env rather than Dev' / Local env

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "^16.5.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.9.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "schedule": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

If anyone has an idea about how to fix it, it would be great
If you require more information, don't hesitate to ask

EDIT : Here is my app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import Navigation from './Navigation/Navigation'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import Store from './Store/configureStore'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={Store} >
          <Navigation />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}


export default App
```

Here is another Git post relative to this subject : https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3859#issuecomment-490979505

Comment: Please paste your `App.js` file, it doesn't hurt to look at some of your code.

Comment: Yes, this is done ! It's surely a Expo environment bug, chance to find solutions are low ...